# How can I revert file association to default

Tags: windows-7

I have tried to open ex4 file by double clicking but could not open it and the dialog box pop up says to find appropriate program from the web. Meanwhile I tried to open the file with 'notepad' by mistakenly checking the 'Always open file of these type with' and afterwards found that all ex4 files when double clicking open up with notepad but does not show up the contents of the file. Now I want to revert back to the starting conditions when ex4 file on double clicking could not be open with any available  editor with dialog box saying to find appropriate programs from the web,as I think it could be harmful to ex4 file without reverting back.Anyone with any knowledge.

Comment: Was the extension previously associated with any program? If not, mis-associating it with Notepad won't really be 'harmful' in any way, unless perhaps it makes it easy for you to open and mistakenly edit (and thus corrupt) the files.

Comment: Related (possible dupes): [How do you remove a default program association for file types in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows), [Delete Windows file association using .reg file](http://superuser.com/questions/51503/delete-windows-file-association-using-reg-file), [How to delete a file association?](http://superuser.com/questions/159927/how-to-delete-a-file-association) etc.